# You are using the tracefile format older than 1.0a5 nam cannot work

Tags: ubuntu-14.04, ns2

when i execute the my tcl file it will shows the following error
"You are using the tracefile format older than 1.0a5
which will not allow you to run namgraph"
iam using ns 2.35 
nam 1.15 
ubuntu 14.04
how to solve this error?
anybody help me please.

hello sir thank for your reply, now i have attached my tcl file link below..
[my tcl file](https://drivenotepad.appspot.com/app?state=%7B%22ids%22:%5B%220B6QgwyZFbRctOWQwZHlpMXU3WUk%22%5D,%22action%22:%22open%22,%22userId%22:%22103296559492254626772%22%7D)

Answer (score 0):

»» when I execute the my tcl file «« : Unknown file.

Please upload your file.tcl to e.g. 'Google Docs'. Your error(s) origins from your file.

P.S. : You will also find ancient examples in ns-2.35/tcl/ex/

-